# What does "While in the service of the company" mean?

Tags: contract-law

I have been offered 5% of a company through a shareholder agreement form (which I have not signed) but am really worried about a clause which essentially states,

> Any IP discovered by me relating to the business while in
>   the service of the Company must be disclosed and becomes the property
>   of the company.

Typically, I might say that service is the time during which I am being paid but there is no wage associated with the shareholding.

I am a contractor and work for other customers, I am concerned that such a clause would mean that I would be obliged to disclose customer secrets as they  are in similar sectors.  Am I over-stressing or should I argue the clause?